# Java Script code is not working in Joomla

Tags: javascript, checkbox, joomla

I created a web-to-lead form using SuiteCRM.  Using the code generated by it,I further enhanced it and added a set of 4-checkboxes.

I saved it as a HTML normal page.  When I open this html page in browser and it correctly display the alert and submits all the required values correctly to prescribed MySQL database table.

Here is the complete code of this html page:

```
<html lang='en_us'><head><base target=”_parent” /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body><style type="text/css"><!--
form#WebToLeadForm, form#WebToLeadForm * {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none; color: #333; font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.6em; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
form#WebToLeadForm {float: left; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 10px;}
form#WebToLeadForm h1 {font-size: 32px; font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(60, 141, 188); color: rgb(247, 247, 247); padding: 10px 20px;}
form#WebToLeadForm h2 {font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; background-color: rgb(60, 141, 188); color: rgb(247, 247, 247); padding: 10px 20px;}
form#WebToLeadForm h3 {font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px 20px;}
form#WebToLeadForm h4 {font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px 20px;}
form#WebToLeadForm h5 {font-size: 8px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px 20px;}
form#WebToLeadForm h6 {font-size: 6px; font-weight: bold; padding: 10px 20px;}
form#WebToLeadForm p {padding: 10px 20px;}
form#WebToLeadForm input,
form#WebToLeadForm select,
form#WebToLeadForm textarea {border: 1px solid #ccc; display: block; float: left; min-width: 170px; padding: 5px;}
form#WebToLeadForm select {background-color: white;}
form#WebToLeadForm input[type="button"],
form#WebToLeadForm input[type="submit"] {display: inline; float: none; padding: 5px 10px; width: auto; min-width: auto;}
form#WebToLeadForm input[type="checkbox"],
form#WebToLeadForm input[type="radio"] {width: 18px; min-width: auto;}
form#WebToLeadForm div.col {display: block; float: left; width: 330px; padding: 10px 20px;}
form#WebToLeadForm div.clear {display: block; float: none; clear: both; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;}
form#WebToLeadForm div.center {text-align: center;}
form#WebToLeadForm div.buttons {padding: 10px 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #f7f7f7}
form#WebToLeadForm label {display: block; float: left; width: 160px; font-weight: bold;}
form#WebToLeadForm span.required {color: #FF0000;}
--></style>
<!-- TODO ??? 
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://localhost/suitecrm/cache/include/javascript/sugar_grp1.js?v=WCpISilUvngJZgJBZ4o1BA'></script> 
--><form id="WebToLeadForm" action="http://localhost/suitecrm/index.php?entryPoint=WebToPersonCapture" method="POST" name="WebToLeadForm">
<h2>FREE Blog Subscription - IT & Networking Blog</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Submitting this form will add you to subscription list of IT & Networking Blog. You will receive email about each new post as soon as published.</p>
<p><img src="http://localhost/images/banners/LeadManagement/Blog-Subscription-image.png" alt="" /></p>
<div class="row">
<div class="col"><label>First Name: <span class="required">*</span></label><input name="first_name" id="first_name" type="text" required="" /></div>
<div class="col"> </div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col"><label>Last Name: <span class="required">*</span></label><input name="last_name" id="last_name" type="text" required="" /></div>
<div class="col"> </div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col"><label>Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label><input name="email1" id="email1" type="email" required="" /></div>
<div class="col"> </div>
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>

<p style="text-align: center;">Select the target lists, you want to join:</p>


<input type="checkbox" id="IT" value="IT">IT<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Process" value="Process">Process<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Management" value="Management">Management<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Education" value="Education">Education<br>


<p style="text-align: center;">100% Privacy! We will never spam you.</p>

<div class="row center buttons" style="text-align: center;"><input class="button" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" onclick="submit_form();" />
<div class="clear"> </div>
</div>
<input name="campaign_id" id="campaign_id" type="hidden" value="13f62ae3-f38d-fe80-a93a-57d4090f764d" /> <input name="assigned_user_id" id="assigned_user_id" type="hidden" value="1" /> <input name="moduleDir" id="moduleDir" type="hidden" value="Prospects" /><input name="prospect_list_id" id="prospect_list_id" type="hidden" value="ac6ce628-de45-4813-d1a0-57e2jgjhr49146" />

<!--my code starts here -->
<input name="list_name_c" id="list_name_c" type="hidden" value="mello" /></div>


</form>


<p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function submit_form()
{

if (typeof(validateCaptchaAndSubmit) != 'undefined')
{
validateCaptchaAndSubmit();
}
else
{
check_webtolead_fields();
//document.WebToLeadForm.submit();
check();

}


}


function check_webtolead_fields()
{
if (document.getElementById('bool_id') != null)
{
var reqs = document.getElementById('bool_id').value;
bools = reqs.substring(0, reqs.lastIndexOf(';'));
var bool_fields = new Array();
var bool_fields = bools.split(';');
nbr_fields = bool_fields.length;
for (var i = 0; i < nbr_fields; i++)

{
if (document.getElementById(bool_fields[i]).value == 'on')
{
document.getElementById(bool_fields[i]).value = 1;
}
else
{
document.getElementById(bool_fields[i]).value = 0;
}
}
}

}


function check()
{

var list_name = "";
var test = document.forms[0];
var txt = "";
var i;

for (i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
{
if (test[i].checked)
{
txt = txt + test[i].value + " ";
}
}
list_name = txt;
alert(list_name);

document.getElementById('list_name_c').value = list_name;

}



// ]]></script>
</p></body></html>
```

But my problem starts when I strips the opening & closing html codes from it.  I created a 'Custom HTML' module in Joomla and pasted the code there and accessed in a article.  The form takes correct shape at the front-end of website.

All the values of 3-fields viz., First Name, Last Name, Email are correctly recorded in database, but checkbox value(s) are not recorded.  Even the alert is blank which occurs immediately after I click on submit/subscribe button.

I don't know why it is not working in JOOMLA 3.

MY OBJECTIVE: To have four checkboxes whose values are appended with " - " and stored in the 'list_name_c' field of database table.

What can I do to make it work?

With thanks,

RK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Java script was not working because of one more form on the final html webpage. The solution was to replace the code line var test = document.forms[0]; with the code line: var test = document.MYFORMNAME; Thanks!